# NumericUpDown error: Value should be between minimum and maximum

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a numericupdown which will retrieve value from database, as following line

```
pd_qty.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(product.qty);
```

remarks: pd_qty is numericupdown, product.qty is string

When I run the form, the error occurs

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>           #translated# error : '9999.0000' is not valid value for 'Value', Value should be between minimum and maximum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`NumericUpDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) has a [`Minimum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.minimum(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Maximum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.maximum(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  If you haven't set these explicitly, the default is minimum 0, maximum 100.  The value you are setting is either less than the minimum, or (very likely) greater than the maximum.

If you need to accept such large numbers, adjust the maximum:
`pd_qty.Maximum = 10000;`